# Terminal.app fonts broken on Mac Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, fonts, terminal.app

About an year ago I installed [gnome fonts](http://www.gnome.org/fonts/) on my MacBook Pro and I use them for Terminal.app

Today I was using Terminal with three windows open and suddenly the app has quit (I don't know if I accidentally pressed command+q) but when I reopened the application fonts looks strange.

I had a screenshot taken before the accident

[image: before]

I did the same screenshot now and here's the result

[image]

I don't know what's happened, I tried to reinstall the fonts, restarted the computer, but with no luck.

One more thing, I use an external screen, I read some posts regarding font issues with external monitors but I had this monitor before this accident and everything worked fine until now.

Please help me to solve this because my eyes were used to that font and now it looks weird to see this different font

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found that OSX can incorrectly determine that your external display doesn't support font smoothing, most often if it's a non-Apple display. To force-enable font smoothing, run the following:

```
defaults -currentHost write -globalDomain AppleFontSmoothing -int 2
```

Comment: I simply love you!!!! You solved my problem. The strange thing is that I bought my monitor two weeks ago and this problem went out just today. I'll vote up your answer as soon as I reach 15 reputation. Thank you.